# the wave equation for the infinite string

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, wave-equation

Considers the wave equation for the infinite string as follow

$$
\begin{cases}
u_{tt}-a^2u_{xx}=f(x,t)=0, -\infty <x<+\infty,t>0 \\
u(x,0)=u_{0}(x), -\infty<x<+\infty \\
u_{t}(x,0)=u_{1}(x),-\infty<x<+\infty
\end{cases}
$$

I knew the way to solve above equation. As you know, its solution is d'Alembert's formula. My question is how to solve it in case $f \not\equiv 0$. Thanks everyone !

Comment: That is a linear equation so the general solution is equal to the general solution to the associated homogeneous equation (with f=0) plus any one solution to the entire equation.  Finding such a single equation depends strongly on how f(x,t) is defined.  For example, if f is a function of t only, you can solve $u_{tt}= f(t)$ by integrating twice.